# How to create a "favorites bar" by dragging table elements into a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/u5vhS/54/ .

What I want to be able to do is drag an app row to the dropdown menu to create a 'favorites bar' of sorts. I was looking at [table drag and drop](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)  to do the table manipulations but I have no idea how I could make the dropdown menu 'accept' the new favorite.  Any plugins or suggestions would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/u5vhS/68/

JS: Using jQuery UI 1.8.16

```
$('#links_table a').draggable({ revert: true, helper: "clone" });
$('ul.dropdown-menu').droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) 
    {
        $( "<li></li>" ).html( ui.draggable.clone()).appendTo( this ); 
    }        
})
$('a.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

​